# File version of Windows exe file as hex number

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am creating an executable on Windows using pyinstaller. I created simple versionfie:

```
VSVersionInfo(
  ffi=FixedFileInfo(
    filevers=(0, 0, 0, 0),
    prodvers=(0, 0, 0, 0)),
  kids=[
    StringFileInfo(
      [
      StringTable(
        u'040904B0',
        [StringStruct(u'FileVersion',    u'0xFF.1'),
         StringStruct(u'ProductVersion', u'0xFF.1')])
      ]), 
    VarFileInfo([VarStruct(u'Translation', [1033, 1200])])
  ]
)
```

I would like that both File version and Product version display *0xFF.1* and what I get is that Product version displays *0xFF.1* and File version *0.0.0.0*: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTEl5.png). Is there a way to achieve it?